# Passing register value in Verilog module as input to another module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, module

I use the XADC IP, for which a module `na7_chseq_xadc` is used to write the digital data from the ADC in registers `adc2_out`, `adc3_out`, and `adc10_out`. In this module, the XADC IP is instantiated.

```
module na7_chseq_xadc(
input clk,
input vauxp2,
input vauxn2,
input vauxp3,
.......
);
register [11:0] adc2_out, adc3_out, adc10_out;
....
adc2_out=data;
.....
adc3_out=data;
....
adc10_out=data;
....
);
endmodule
```

I have another module within the same project (separate Verilog file) which generates the control signals and serial data for a DAC connected to the same board (Nexys A7). The module name is `pmod_dac_test`.

```
module pmod_dac_test(
input [11:0] auxp2,
input [11:0] auxp3,
input [11:0] auxp10,
input clk,
output sclk_out,
output sd_out,
output sync_out
);
.....
);
endmodule
```

The values in the registers `adc2_out`, `adc3_out`, and `adc10_out` from "`na7_chseq_xadc`" need to be passed as inputs to module "`pmod_dac_test`" (`auxp2`, `auxp3`, `auxp10`). I understand the module "pmod_dac_test" can be instantiated within "na7_chseq_xadc". Is it a correct way to pass the values?
If yes, will the following work? Is it okay to instantiate only 3 input ports of the module?

```
//within na7_chseq_xadc
pmod_dac_test inst1(
     .auxp2(adc2_out);
     .auxp3(adc3_out);
     .auxp10(adc10_out)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct way to connect signals to a module instance, but you need to use commas, not semicolons, between connections.

Also, you must make connections to all ports.

Here is a code example that compiles without errors:

```
module pmod_dac_test(
    input [11:0] auxp2,
    input [11:0] auxp3,
    input [11:0] auxp10,
    input clk,
    output sclk_out,
    output sd_out,
    output sync_out
);
endmodule


module na7_chseq_xadc(
   input clk,
   input vauxp2,
   input vauxn2,
   input vauxp3
);

reg [11:0] adc2_out, adc3_out, adc10_out, data;
always @* begin
    adc2_out=data;
    adc3_out=data;
    adc10_out=data;
end

//within na7_chseq_xadc
pmod_dac_test inst1 (
    .clk(clk),
    .auxp2(adc2_out),
    .auxp3(adc3_out),
    .auxp10(adc10_out),
    .sclk_out(),
    .sd_out(),
    .sync_out()
);
endmodule
```

You need to decide what to connect to the following `pmod_dac_test` output ports:

```
.sclk_out(),
.sd_out(),
.sync_out()
```

Comment: Right. I see what happens now. The output ports are connected to top level pins. When I instantiated the "pmod_dac_test" module again, it raised off a lot of constraint errors - the "pmod_dac_test" modules and a "copy" of the same (the instance) have output ports connected to the same top level pins. I think instantiating the module was a bad idea - it had the communication protocol code in it. I shall try to add the ADC code into the "pmod_dac_test" itself - no instances (copies), and just one file to handle. Shall try this for now. Thanks.

Comment: @Suhanya: You're welcome.  Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)